# App Insights timestamp: what time it reflects?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I've built a custom telemetry tracking in my app using App Insights. I manually start operation and finalize it. Does anybody know what datetime the timestamp in the request reflects? Beginning of the operation or its end?
(asking because detected some weird things related to this, suspecting App Insights)

Comment: what's the issue do you have, about the weird thing?

Comment: My application logs time when message has been sent to the queue and from app insights (timestamp) I get time when handling operation finishes. Sometimes time between the message was sent/finished and time that handler was processing the message look weird: processing time is greater than "Full or Lead time". Trying to understand where the problem is.

Comment: Do we know if the timestamp is based on the clock of the machine that sent the message, or is it the time in the cloud?

Answer (score 0):

The timestamp means the time when the record was created by the data source. So in your case, it's the beginning of the operation. Please refer to [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/log-standard-properties#timegenerated-and-timestamp) for more details.

But due to `Log data ingestion time`, there maybe latency. For more details, please refer to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/data-ingestion-time).

Comment: If the answer is helpful, please help accept it as answer, as per this [link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=active#tab-top). Thanks very much.

Comment: I just checked, timestamp differs from ingestion_time().

Comment: So what is timestamp then: time when I start the operation? Or when I finish it? Or when it is ingested in AppInsigts data source? Confused (